# Is a warp drive faster than a hyperdrive?

Tags: star-wars, star-trek, warp, hyperspace

What's faster: a warp drive from Star Trek, or a hyperdrive from Star Wars?

Comment: This is leaning towards a shark vs gorilla question - could do with some revision

Comment: Neither.  [Ludicrous Speed](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mk7VWcuVOf0)!

Comment: Gorilla.  Clearly.

Comment: I remember one somewhat intoxicated, very early morning, con debate on the relative merits of spindizzies vs Bergenholms....

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't even compare the two. Hyperdrives allow you to travel around the galaxy in a matter of days whereas warp drives take *decades*, requiring numerous refueling operations along the way. However, the disparity between the two technologies stems more from the style of the two franchises than anything else:

Star Wars is an action saga, and people needed to get places fast. The Millennium falcon still manages to fly from Hoth to Bespin in the Empire Strikes Back even *without* its hyperdrive. Clearly this makes absolutely zero scientific sense, but that's Star wars: it's more science fantasy than Science Fiction.

Star Trek on the other hand is (or at least was before JJ Abhrams) a cerebral, slow, nerdy, and mostly serious franchise where the believe-ability of the technology and science is an important part of the show. The warp drive is limited because [it actually could exist under our current understanding of physics.](http://www.space.com/6649-star-trek-warp-drive-impossible.html)

So while hyperdrives in star wars are infinitely more powrfull than warp drives in star trek, the comparison is a nonsensical one. It's like pointing out that the TARDIS is faster than the space shuttle--DUH.

Also, it should be noted that hyperdrives, while exceptionally complicated pieces of equipment, are essentially one device. You can buy one as a unit, as evidenced by the Phantom Menace. Warp drives on the other hand (at least ones of any meaningful power) are massive integrated systems involving nacelles, a warp core, antimatter pods, plasma coolant, and a *lot* more. This makes warp drive much more difficult to maintain.

The only advantage for Warp Drive I can think of is that apparently travelling by hyperdrive is very risky if one's navigational calculations are off. To quote Han Solo:

> Traveling through hyperspace isn't like dusting crops, boy! Without precise calculations we could fly right through a star or bounce too close to a supernova and that'd end your trip real quick, wouldn't it?

The warp drives systems take care of this via the [navigational deflector](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Navigational_deflector). However, should the deflector be damaged, the ship will sustain serious damage at high velocities, as in [The Year of Hell](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Year_of_Hell#Second_iteration).

Also, Warp Cores can explode catastrophically if antimatter containment is lost, making them a very juicy target in combat. I do not believe that Hyperdrives share this weakness.

Comment: Assuming, our galaxy and the galaxy far-far away have same size..

Comment: Star Wars ships have a 'backup' hyperdrive in case the main one fails...

Comment: @SachinShekhar I think that if the SW and ST FTL were of comparable speed and SW just had a smaller galaxy, the SW galaxy would have collapsed into a black hole long before intelligent life could have had time to evolve >_>

Comment: IIRC, it was established a while back that the SW galaxy is slightly larger than the Milky Way.  This, however, may no longer be canon (since Disney).

Comment: @jono A larger galaxy wouldn't collapse into a black hole. Rather, it would just be so large that it would no longer be gravitationally bound (and hence would stop being a galaxy).

Comment: @forest The opposite, I said that if the SW galaxy was so small that this would make sense, it would collapse into a black hole. Because it would need to be very, very small.