# Hyperdrive vs Warp drive. Which is fastest?

Tags: star-trek, star-wars

In Star Trek Warp Factor 36 is the highest FTL speed while in star wars I think the fastest canon was 0.4. So which is faster?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I refer you to [this](http://www.startrek.com/boards-topic/33349375/warp-drive-vs-hyperdrive?qid=1161#trivia_box) series of posts (especially the last two posts) where it is found that hyperdrive is faster than the warp drive, based on the time required to traverse the respective galaxies and relative size.  Also see [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34994/is-a-warp-drive-better-than-a-hyperdrive?rq=1) question.